# Magento2 resize images on list mode

Tags: magento2, product-images

In my custom theme for `product/list.phtml` file and list mode i use the following code for gallery images:

```
<?php $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
<div class="custom-product-gallery">
<?php foreach($images as $child): ?>
    <div class="slider-item-inner">
        <img src="<?php echo $child->getUrl(); ?>" >
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In `Magento 1.x`, I used:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(100, 100); ?>
```

How i can resize the images in `Magento 2` ?

Answer (score 1):

In `Magento 2` i use next code:

```
$_productImageHelper = $this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
<?php $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>

<?php foreach($images as $child): ?>
$imageUrl = $productImageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_large')->setImageFile($child->getFile())->resize(192,161)->getUrl();
<div class="slider-item-inner"><img src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" ></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

it works for me

Comment: Accept the answer if this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To resize magento 2 product image you can used the following code,

```
class YOURCLASS extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     protected $_productloader;
     protected $productimghelper;

     public function __construct(Context $context, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productloader,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $producthelper)
    {

        $this->_productloader = $productloader;
        $this->productimghelper = $producthelper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function YOURFUNCTION()
    {
        $product = $this->_productloader->load(123); // 123 is your product Id
        $imgURL = $this->productimghelper->init($product, 'category_page_list')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(FALSE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(120,90)->getUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: How i can use your code in foreach by images?

Comment: you need just pass your product_id from foreach look and call above function, and then just take responce of this function to show Image.

Comment: I do not understend how i can use function in foreach, how i can put image url, function return only 1 image url

<?php foreach($images as $child): ?>
    <div class="slider-item-inner">
        <img src="<?php echo $child->getUrl(); ?>" >
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: Share your complete code where you want to display images.